# Grails 2.2.2 error on using own tag lib

Tags: grails, taglib

I create my own tag lib. On use i get error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerInvocationException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.isArtefactOfType() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource) values: [TagLib, file [D:\domain\grails-app\taglib\ext\domain\DomainTagLib.groovy]]
```

Possible solutions: isArtefactOfType(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class), isArtefactOfType(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Source of TagLib:

```
package ext.domain
class DomainTagLib {

    def contractorFullReq = {attrs, body ->
        def Organization organization = attrs?.organization
        out << organization?.shortName
    }
}
```

Comment: Bug fixed by updating to new version of grails 2.2.3.